# How to access city name from the below mapping in python by creating dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I Have below mapping,

[image: Mapping Table here]

and I need to use that city name base on name and code,

for ex: if name = a , code = 2 the city should be "nagpur"

like that I need to access this mapping ,
So how should I do it in python by creating dictionary of dictionary

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can't have dictionaries as dictionary keys, but you can have tuples, i.e. `my_dict = {("a", 2): "nagpur"}` is valid and `my_dict[("a", 2)]` will return `"nagpur"`.

Comment: "I Have below mapping," I don't see a "mapping"; I see a clipped screenshot. I have no idea how it relates to your program. Is it a Pandas Dataframe being displayed by some graphical IDE for Python? Is it a screenshot of a .CSV file in a spreadsheet editing program? Is it something else? Are you for example trying to read the data *out of an image*, as if it were a human mentally processing it?

Comment: @ Karl Knechtel, its screenshot of .csv , and I need to use this mapping in python code by creating dictionaries

Comment: Post your csv instead image, please. And you can use Pandas to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I design new way by creating python dictionary:

```
d = {"a": {0:"mumbai",
       1:"pune",
       2: "nagpur",
       3: "surat"},

 "b": {0: "newyork",
       1: "puri",
       2: "delhi",
       3: "aasam"}

 }

city = d["a"][2]
print(f"city : {city}")
```

it gives output is `"nagpur"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict of list:

```
mapping = {
  'a': ['mumbai','pune','nagpur','surat'],
  'b': ['Newyork','puri','delhi','aasam']
}
```

```
>>> mapping['a'][2]
'nagpur'
```